# Javascript forEach not giving same output as a normal for loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, callback

Hello I'm running some tests to see if the output of both is true. The thing is that given these conditions:

```js
var callback = function (num) {
 return num % 2 === 0
}

console.log($$$.any([1, 3, 4], callback) === true)
console.log($$$.any([1, 11, 111], callback) === false)
```

I have to create a function that gives as a result in both cases true. I did it with a for loop but I can't get the same result with a forEach, why is that?:

```js
// My for loop function:

$$$ = {
  any: function (arr, callback) {
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i ++) {
    if (callback(arr[i])) {
    return true;
    }
   }
  return false;
  }
}

// My forEach function:

$$$={
 any: function(array, callback){
  array.forEach(function(value){
   // console.log(value)
   if (callback(value)) {
    return true;
   } 
   // return false;
  })
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to walk through your program step by step.

Comment: whoever just used the "cannot be reproduced error / typo" close reason - you're wrong.  This is a _logic_ error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second version, the `return true` in the inner callback function only returns from that callback function, and doesn't cause the outer function to return.

The `.forEach` loop will run to completion, and then the `.any` function itself *always* returns `false`.

FWIW, `.forEach` isn't really suitable for a `.any` function because there's no way to terminate the iteration over the elements as soon as a match is found, and it's therefore less efficient than it could be.  For example, you might have an array with 10000 elements, but using `.forEach` it'll keep on looping, even if the very first element satisfied your predicate.

That said, if you really must use `.forEach`, though, the solution would be:

```
function all(array, callback) {
    var result = false;
    array.forEach(function(value) {
        if (callback(value)) {
            result = true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

with a further optimisation possible to at least avoid calling the user supplied callback once a match is found:

```
function all(array, callback) {
    var result = false;
    array.forEach(function(value) {
        if (!result && callback(value)) {
            result = true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

NB: JavaScript already has a function that does what you require - [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to get the same result with a forEach?

Comment: @Defoe there is, by having a variable that is initially set to `false` in the outer scope that's then set to `true` inside the callback if the predicate matches, and then returning that variable.  You shouldn't, though, for the efficiency reasons I outlined above.

Comment: Ok @Alnitak I see, I would use the some function in other cases. Could you please put your last suggestion of the forEach solution in an answer so I can validate it?